# Lua property accessor

Tags: properties, lua

I'm confused by how Lua properties are working in some of the code I'm trying to maintain. I've spent a good amount of time in the Lua documentation before this. So...

There is a function in one of those Lua tables, like this (we'll call this the 'nested tables' example):

```
function addItem(item)

index = itemTable.getIndex(item.position[1], item.position[2])

itemTable.items[index] = item

end;


a = Xpl3dSwitch { position = { 27, 0, 1, 1} }
itemTable.addItem(a) --doesn't seem to 'register' the position property
```

whereas

```
a = Xpl3dSwitch { }

a.position[0] = 27
a.position[1] = 0

itemTable.addItem(a) --this 'registers' the position properties
```

...etc, seems to work. Why are the position tables not sticking in the 'nested table' example?

Also, regarding 'a = Xpl3dSwitch { }' - is it an object constructor? It's not clear from the Lua 'documentation' what this is.

Comment: Lua doesn't have properties (do you mean fields?). Also, `foo { ... }` is a shortcut for `foo({...})` (ie its a function call)

Comment: If that doesn't clear it up, please show the code for Xpl3dSwitch.

Comment: Yes I mean fields...and unfortunately I don't have the full code for Xpl3dSwitch.

Comment: Then we can't really help. What `Xpl3dSwitch` does with the passed table is it's own business; it might be ignoring it entirely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look inside the table a and compare them. That should point you in the direction where the error happens.

to look inside a use something like:

```
function getTableContent(tab, str)
str = str or "table"
for i, v in pairs(tab) do
    if type(v) == "table" and v ~= _G then
        str = str.."->"..tostring(i)
        getTableContent(v, str)
    else
        print(str.."  Index: "..tostring(i).."  Value: "..tostring(v))
    end
end
end


getTableContent(a)
io.read()
```

Once you know how the working and the not working one are structured you should be able to make the adjustments needed.

Edit:

Also you could use:

a = Xpl3dSwitch { }

a.position = {27, 0, 1, 1}